# Magento Custom Admin Module gives 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9

I have been trying to get an Admin module running for updating some prices. But I keep getting a 404 error. I followed this tutorial:
https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/m1wiki/pages/14024903/Create+a+custom+module+with+a+custom+database+table

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <config>
<modules>
    <Speedcrete_PriceUpdate>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Speedcrete_PriceUpdate>
</modules>
<admin>
   <routers>
       <!-- Includes our controller, so when we add the adminhtml menu item below, it is found! -->
       <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <priceupdate before="Mage_Adminhtml">Speedcrete_PriceUpdate_Adminhtml</priceupdate>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
   </routers>
  </admin>
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <priceupdate module="priceupdate">
            <title>PriceUpdate</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>              
            <children>
                <items module="priceupdate">
                    <title>Manage Items</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>priceupdate/adminhtml_priceupdate</action>
                </items>
            </children>
        </priceupdate>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <priceupdate>
                        <title>PriceUpdate Module</title>
                        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                    </priceupdate>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>  
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <priceupdate>
                <file>priceupdate.xml</file>
            </priceupdate>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>  
<global>
    <models>
        <priceupdate>
            <class>Speedcrete_PriceUpdate_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>priceupdate_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </priceupdate>
        <priceupdate_mysql4>
            <class>Speedcrete_PriceUpdate_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <priceupdate>
                    <table>priceupdate</table>
                </priceupdate>
            </entities>
        </priceupdate_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <priceupdate_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Speedcrete_PriceUpdate</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </priceupdate_setup>
        <priceupdate_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </priceupdate_write>
        <priceupdate_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </priceupdate_read>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <priceupdate>
            <class>Speedcrete_PriceUpdate_Block</class>
        </priceupdate>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <priceupdate>
            <class>Speedcrete_PriceUpdate_Helper</class>
        </priceupdate>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

app/code/community/Speedcrete/PriceUpdate/controllers/Adminhtml/PriceUpdateController.php

```
class Speedcrete_PriceUpdate_Adminhtml_PriceUpdateController extends 
 Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
  public function _initAction()
  {
    die('hello world 1');
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('priceupdate/items')
        ->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Items Manager'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Item Manager'));

    return $this;
}

public function indexAction() {
    die('hello world 2');
    $this->_initAction();      
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('priceupdate/adminhtml_priceupdate'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}

/**
 * Product grid for AJAX request.
 * Sort and filter result for example.
 */
public function gridAction()
{
    die('hello world');
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
           $this->getLayout()->createBlock('priceupdate/adminhtml_priceupdate_grid')->toHtml()
    );
}
```

The rest are edit, save and delete actions.

If anything else needed please ask

Comment: try logging out of admin and back in again

Comment: Tried that, cleared the cache (in fact the cache is disabled).

Answer (score 0):

```
<menu>
            <priceupdate module="priceupdate">
                <title>PriceUpdate</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>              
                <children>
                    <items module="priceupdate">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>priceupdate/adminhtml_priceupdate</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </priceupdate>
        </menu>
```

it should be

```
<menu>
        <priceupdate module="priceupdate">
            <title>PriceUpdate</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>              
            <children>
                <items module="priceupdate">
                    <title>Manage Items</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml_priceupdate/priceupdate</action>
                </items>
            </children>
        </priceupdate>
    </menu>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that hasn't worked, the routing doesn't even get to the controller.

Comment: i did change code please check it

Comment: @ScottLunnon Have you checked?

Comment: Checked and still does not work!